# Como retornar as palavras que mais aparecem em uma coluna?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho essa tabela abaixo no qual possui duas colunas, sendo `id` e `description`:

```
CREATE TABLE myBigTable (
    id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    description TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Após inserir alguns registros, fiz um *select* simples e resultou nesta abaixo:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id |     description       |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | joão de santo cristo  |
| 2  | eduardo e mô nica     |
| 3  | santo cristo joão     |
| 4  | cristo tadeu joão     |
| 5  | juazeiro do joão      |
+----+-----------------------+
```

Gostaria de um *select* que retornasse a quantidade de vezes que cada palavra aparece numa determinada coluna, como por exemplo na coluna `description`. Abaixo segue o retorno no qual seria desejado, contendo a palavra e a quantidade. Vejam:

```
+------------+----------+
|    work    |    qnt   |
+------------+----------+
|    joão    |    4     |
|   cristo   |    3     |
|   santo    |    2     |
|    ...     |   ...    |
+------------+----------+
```

Fiz um pequeno teste usando LIKE, porém eu tenho que colocar a palavra no qual quero que me retorn

```
SELECT count(*) as qnt FROM `phrase` WHERE description LIKE "%joao%"
```

Retorno:

```
+----------+
|   qnt    |
+----------+
|    4     |
+----------+
```

Como seria um *select* para retornar as palavras que mais aparece em uma determinada coluna? É possível fazer isso usando apenas recursos do banco de dados?

<sup>**Nota:** não precisaria ser necessariamente a quantidade de vezes que uma palavra aparece, mas sim, se possível, a quantidade de linhas que ela se encontra.</sup>

Comment: Anda ouvindo muito [Legião Urbana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yy_QmWzcqcs) - [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qr0378vrXA) :P

Comment: @Bonifazio sempre! =)

Comment: Acho uma pergunta bem complexa, não sei se existe um jeito performático pra fazer isso :P primeiro teria que explodir cada palavra de cada linha, e depois contar usando LIKE "% string %" e excluindo aquelas que já entraram na contagem...

Comment: Seria um misto desta [função](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5928675/3956218) com [esta logica](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1503980/3956218)

Comment: Voce tem um tamanho máximo de palavras. Por exemplo mil? Nao respondeu á pergunta xP

Comment: @BrunoCosta não tem o tamanho máximo, mas eu precisaria no máximo 100, que já seria suficiente para tomar decisões. E agora, respondeu?!

Comment: o ponto do seu teste é se voce tiver a mesma palavra no mesmo campo ex. `joão de são joão del rey`, teria que contar 2x certo?

Comment: to com o mesmo problema se resolver marca resolvido em qual

Answer (score 4):

Encontrei uma solucao online, dou todo o crédito ao [autor do artigo](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql.html) que arranjou uma solucao engenhosa para fazer um split duma string em `Mysql`. Contudo a solucao dele requqer que voce crie uma tabela de números com tantas entradas quanto o número de palavras que voce suporta.

Aqui fica um exemplo:

Esquema:

```
Create table Data2(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  nome nvarchar(255)
);

insert into Data2 (nome) values ('ola');
insert into Data2 (nome) values ('ola adeus');
insert into Data2 (nome) values ('adeus ola');
insert into Data2 (nome) values ('gelados ola');
insert into Data2 (nome) values ('viva');

create table numbers (
  n int
);

insert into numbers values (1);
insert into numbers values (2);
--...
```

Query:

```
select nome, count(1) totalLinhas from (
  select id, nome, count(1) as total from ( 
    select 
      id, 
      substring_index(
        substring_index(nome, ' ', n), 
        ' ', 
        -1
      ) as nome
    from Data2
    join numbers
      on char_length(nome) 
        - char_length(replace(nome, ' ', '')) 
        >= n - 1
  ) t1
  group by id, nome
)t2
group by nome
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77735/21)

Comment: Mas ali no contexto eu falo : "...retornasse a quantidade de vezes que cada palavra aparece... "

Comment: @AckLay Pode fazer [join com a própria tabela](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7edf1/1), se confiar que ela tem registos suficientes

Comment: testei o fiddle, e esta retornando ola apenas 4x, não deveria ser 6x?

Comment: @BrunoCosta agora que li as letras míudas do post dele, acho que eu que vou ter q fazer essa pergunta então ... kkkk

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como isso ficaria no MySQL, estou sem o banco aqui para fazer o teste, mas no sql server seria assim;

```
declare @tabela table
(
    id int,
    description varchar(500)
) 

declare @tabelaAux table
(
    description varchar(500)
) 

declare @texto varchar(200), @textoAux varchar(200), @Index int,@Separador varchar(2) = ' '

--insert into @tabela values
--( 1,'joão de santo cristo')  
--,(2,'eduardo e mô nica')    
--,(3,'santo cristo joão')    
--,(4,'cristo tadeu joão')   
--,(5,'juazeiro do joão') 

insert into @tabela values 
( 1,'joão de santo cristo joão carlos joão joão de santo cristo joão carlos joão  ') ,
(2,'eduardo e mô nica') ,
(3,'joão santo joão cristo cristo  cristo cristo  joão') ,
(4,'cristo tadeu joão') ,
(5,'juazeiro do joão')


-- Cursor para percorrer os nomes dos objetos 
DECLARE cursor_tabela CURSOR FOR
select description from @tabela

    -- Abrindo Cursor para leitura
    OPEN cursor_tabela

    -- Lendo a próxima tabela
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tabela INTO @texto

    -- Percorrendo linhas do cursor (enquanto houverem)
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
         SET @Index = charIndex(@Separador,@texto)
         WHILE (@Index > 0) BEGIN  
            set @textoAux = SubString(@texto,1,@Index-1);
            insert into @tabelaAux( description) values(@textoAux)
            set @texto =  SubString(@texto, @Index+1, len(@texto) - @Index)
            SET @Index = charIndex(@Separador,@texto)

        END
        insert into @tabelaAux( description) values(@texto)

    -- Lendo a próxima linha
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tabela INTO @texto
    END

-- Fechando Cursor para leitura
CLOSE cursor_tabela

-- Desalocando o cursor
DEALLOCATE cursor_tabela

select count(description)total,  description from @tabelaAux
group by description
```

Saída;

```
total   description
2   
2   carlos
7   cristo
2   de
1   do
1   e
1   eduardo
11  joão
1   juazeiro
1   mô
1   nica
3   santo
1   tadeu
```

Comment: testei com essa massa e não contou certo man: `insert into @tabela values
( 1,'joão de santo cristo joão carlos joão')  
,(2,'eduardo e mô nica')    
,(3,'joão santo joão cristo joão')    
,(4,'cristo tadeu joão')   
,(5,'juazeiro do joão')`

Comment: @andrepaulo, verdade, Corrigido.

Comment: Estou usando o mysql, e vou tentar dar uma olhada para converter isso pra la. A solução do nosso amigo abaixo na outra resposta parece funcionar para poucos registros, agora testei para 78688 linhas e demorou tanto que o tempo expirou... vou continuar testando.

Comment: @AckLay, essa é ema questão que exige muito processamento, se você for fazer a consulta constantemente, seria o ideal ter uma tabela que armazenasse cada palavra separadamente com um campo que somasse a cada vez que fosse incluído + 1,  depois só seria fazer o select. para sempre ter ela atualizada depois uma trigger seria interessante.